# UB with typeid invocation

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, typeid

I've written the code for the understanding `typeid` operator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct C;

struct B
{
    long unsigned int hash;

    B(C *c);
};

struct C : B
{
    C() : B(this)
    {
        cout << "C()" << endl;
    }
};

B::B(C *c)
{
    hash = typeid(*c).hash_code(); //1, UB?
}

C c;
int main()
{
    cout << c.hash << endl;
    cout << typeid(c).hash_code() << endl;
}
```

I think the code I've written produce UB at `//1` because 12.7/5 says

> If the operand of typeid refers to the object under construction or
>   destruction and the static type of the operand is neither the
>   constructor or destructor’s class nor one of its bases, the result of
>   typeid is undefined

Right?

Comment: (maybe) final edit. plz see >o<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is UB. Look at `C`'s constructor.

```
C()
    :            // 1
      B(this)    // 2
{                // 3
    ...
```

Each object should have something about its typeinfo, So we can guess constructor initialize it.

As you know, standard gives much freedom to implementations. Maybe it didn't decide whether constructor should initialize typeinfo in `// 1` or `// 3`. If one implementation decided to initialize it in `// 3`, You would get wrong result because typeinfo isn't initialized in `// 2`.

---

<strike>*(However, Both VC++ 2013 and g++ 4.8.3 give a correct result. Notice that >o<)*</strike>

I was correct. The reason [we could get correct result](http://ideone.com/D4HoXo) is that **`C` has no virtual functions.** As you know, RTTI doesn't enabled if there's no virtual functions. So compiler generated typeinfo from static type, which is `C`.

With virtual functions, it generates UB's result.

```
struct B
{
    long unsigned int hash;

    B(C *c);

    virtual ~B() = default; // here.
};
```

[(live example)](http://ideone.com/7IiYP0)

Comment: The static type of the operand is `C`. The constructor's class is `B`. `C` is not a base of `B`

Comment: @MattMcNabb Oh, my eye seems to have screwed :( Let me think for a while

Comment: I don't see what the second part of your post is getting at, the standard quote we are looking at makes no mention of virtual functions. (Just because your example with no virtual functions appears to work, doesn't mean that it isn't UB)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes, even if there's no virtual functions, it's still UB. I explained why we got correct result despite that. My explanation seems not enough >o<

Comment: Thank for your answer, but I would like to ask one more question. Is behavior will be underfined If we replace `typeid` to `dynamic_cast`? Example : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0122e586dc9ef12

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Sorry for my very late reply... I think it should be UB because `dynamic_cast` should use typeinfo at runtime. [And it seems to be UB.](http://ideone.com/6i7Yi9)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is undefined behaviour.

The previous sentence says

> When `typeid` is used in ... a function called ... from a constructor
>   ..., if the operand of `typedid` refers to the object under construction ..., `typeid` yields the `std::type_info` representing the constructor's class.

The relevant object under construction is `c`, and the static type of the operand of `typeid` is C, so the result is the type of C.

The B constructor is also running, but `c` is not "the object under construction" there, so the sentence you quoted does not apply.

Comment: But the static type of c (aka `C`) is not a base for `B`. You might not understand me correctly. I mean UB is produced during the construction of `C c;` and `B`'s constructor is invoked when `c` is under construction.

Comment: I believe I understand you. `c` is not the object under construction in B's constructor - only its B base sub-object is.

Comment: I've understood what you mean. But what does "object is under construction" means? I think it means "after the construction was started but object lifetime is still not". Since B's constructor is invoked during the `c`'s construction and this implies that we apply `typeid(c)` to the object under construction. Could you point me to where I'm wrong in that reason?

Comment: The language used is "in a constructor or destructor ... the object under construction or destruction", which seems clear to me. Notice that it's *the* object, not *an* object. In B's constructor the object under construction is the B base sub-object; in C's constructor the object under construction is `c`.